# Query SQL for count value minus

Tags: mysql

I have a Database. contains several tables, there is a table name

> stockdiary

, There is a field

> units

example :

```
**units**
-3
7
-8
-2
20
```

there are negative and positive value, how to query for summing the negative value only

Comment: do a where clause to only get the negative values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN units<0 THEN units ELSE 0 END) as NegativeTotal 
from stockdiary
```

OR

```
SELECT SUM(units) as NegativeTotal 
    from stockdiary where units<0
```

Comment: thank u so much, this went well **SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN units<0 THEN units ELSE 0 END) as NegativeTotal 
from stockdiary**

Comment: welcome you should accept my ans so everyone know this it is work

Comment: oh you can see there is a right symbol you have to click there or you can google it how

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(units) 
FROM stockdiary
WHERE units < 0
```